# I need help formulating a specific regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I do not consider myself a newbie in regex, but I seem to have found a problem that stumped me (it's also Friday evening, so brain not at peak performance).

I am trying to substitute a place-holder inside a string with some other value. I am having great difficulty getting a syntax that behaves the way I want.
My place-holder has this format: `{swap}`

I want it to capture and replace these:

```
    {swap}    # NewValue
    x{swap}x  # xNewValuex
    {swap}x   # NewValuex
    x{swap}   # xNewValue
```

But I want it to NOT match these:

```
    {{swap}}    # NOT {NewValue}
    x{{swap}}x  # NOT x{NewValue}x
    {{swap}}x   # NOT {NewValue}x
    x{{swap}}   # NOT x{NewValue}
```

In all of the above, `x` can be any string, of any length, be it "word" or not.

I'm trying to do this using python3's `re.sub()` but anytime I satisfy one subset of criteria I lose another in the process. I'm starting to think it might not be possible to do in a single command.

Cheers!

Comment: You should be able to use `(?<!\{)\{swap\}(?!\})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
s1 = "x{swap}x"
s2 = "x{{swap}}x"
pattern = r"(?<!\{)\{[^}]+\}(?!})"
re.sub(pattern, "foo", s1)
#'xfoox'
re.sub(pattern, "foo", s2)
#'x{{swap}}x'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module, you can use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
{{.*?}}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|{.*?}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/L0msuy/1/).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
{{.*?}}(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # match any {{...}} and "throw them away"
|                     # or ...
{.*?}                 # match your desired pattern
```

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'{{.*?}}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|{.*?}')

string = """
    {swap}    
    x{swap}x  
    {swap}x   
    x{swap}   

    {{swap}}    
    x{{swap}}x  
    {{swap}}x   
    x{{swap}}"""

string = rx.sub('NewValue', string)
print(string)
```

This yields:

```
NewValue    
xNewValuex  
NewValuex   
xNewValue   

{{swap}}    
x{{swap}}x  
{{swap}}x   
x{{swap}}
```

---

For the sake of completeness, you can also achieve this with `Python`'s own `re` module but here, you'll need a slightly adjusted pattern as well as a replacement function:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'{{.*?}}|({.*?})')

string = """
    {swap}    
    x{swap}x  
    {swap}x   
    x{swap}   

    {{swap}}    
    x{{swap}}x  
    {{swap}}x   
    x{{swap}}"""


def repl(match):
    if match.group(1) is not None:
        return "NewValue"
    else:
        return match.group(0)

string = rx.sub(repl, string)
print(string)
```